# How to dynamically change borderColor of series in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using following code to change the bordercolor of series, but it's not working out.

```
chart.options.plotOptions.series.borderWidth = '3px';
chart.options.plotOptions.series.borderColor = '#FF0000';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X68Z7/)

Can anyone please suggest?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use series.update() method as shown below, this method updates the options and data for the series. You have to run this method with each and every method to get the settings applied to all the series

`chart.series[0].update({
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: '#FF0000'
})`

Updated your js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X68Z7/1/)

I hope this is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I don't want the vertical border between two series.

Comment: I need to iterate on each data to check condition whether it is required to add border or not, something like formatter function. It is like having different borders for different values.

Comment: you can do that for the individual point as well, updated the fiddle for individual point at http://jsfiddle.net/X68Z7/2/

Comment: Yeah, that can be done, but I need different border colors for Jan Feb march depending on the values of y.

Comment: For example, if its 10, then it should be green and if more than 20 then red.

Comment: you can maintain the list of colors in a array and update the color as well keeping in the loop, you can have your conditions inside them as well http://jsfiddle.net/X68Z7/3/

Comment: Yeah, thanks for help, it works well, but in case if I have more than 50 categories, then it will iterate for all 50 values to update the border color, which reduces the response time while loading the chart.

Comment: UI is unresponsive in case, if we have more than 100 categories/bars. Is there any other option to set borderColor.

Comment: please check the fiddle, for issue, UI becomes unresponsive for a while, http://jsfiddle.net/sbHHw/

Comment: you want to have the border color on demand or immediately after the chart is rendered

Comment: immediately after the chart and different border colors which i can save in array.

Comment: then you can go with the callback of the chart. here is a updated fiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/X68Z7/6/

Comment: the thing is like when I tested with about 50 categories it took around 5secs to load.

Comment: For 100 categories, it will go upto 10secs, which will be bad.

Comment: This is actually the best approach in highcharts. The `series.update()` method really helped me a lot.